# Rewrite Base in Htaccess in Subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

All my paths on my website are relative URLs and start with / which is fine in production, but I brought it back over to development and put it under a path of /app I tried to use the RewriteBase setting but it doesn't change any of the paths on the website. Am I missing somehting?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app/
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/(.+)$ $1.php?type=$2&loan-type=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$ $1.php?type=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

Root htaccess settings that redirect all of root to /apps not just the subolder of /apps.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(?!app/)(.+)$ /app/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: What would then?

Comment: You will need a rule in site root .htaccess to prefix `/app` before every URI

Comment: Ok thanks, adding to the root is what did it.

Comment: Well I added below code and it worked for the subpages but now the root pages just redirect to the sub url.

Comment: Any idea on why it just changes everything to that subfolder?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(?!app/)(.+)$ app/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: It still rewrites my root to /app though.

Comment: Keep this rule as your top rule. If it still doesn't work then post your site root .htaccess in question

Comment: See above, for update. It still just redirects the root to /app/

Comment: Close, it makes the index at the root lose it's style sheet though and no other pages at the root level work.

Comment: ok try: `RewriteRule ^(?!app/|index\.|[^/]+\.(js|css)$)(.+)$ app/$1 [L,NC]`

Comment: Didn't work, it should be way simpler than it seems to be.

Comment: ok, check your access log and post all requests that you see there once you load landing page.